# Is there any way to automatically fire setTimeout events with WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, chromium

I'd like to run tests against some pages that have a bunch of setTimeout code. One option would be for me to wait until this code has run, but ideally I'd like to force the code to run as soon as the page has been loaded.

One approach I've thought of is to inject to javascript like the following into the page prior to the page being evaluated:

```
var originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(a, t) {
    originalSetTimeout(a, 0);
}
```

I'm not sure *how* to do that though, or if there are better approaches that I'm overlooking.

Note that removing the setTimeout code on the pages I'm testing isn't an option here.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a

```
driver.get('http://mypage.com')
```

WebDriver will wait until the page has loaded. Once that is done you can then do

```
driver.execute_script('var originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
                      window.setTimeout = function(a, t) {
                         originalSetTimeout(a, 0);
                      }')
```

which will possibly do what you want and **should** run as soon as possible.

Comment: If it waits until the page has loaded won't it have already executed the original setTimeout call, prior to the execute_script overriding its behaviour?

Comment: Possibly but there is no way to override the get() call